# How to sort a date in String format using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery

This table is using the [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin.
The table has three columns:

- Name
- Description
- Date

The table sorts by Name ascending by default. 
The values in the Date column are not numerical, but are stored as a human readable string such as:
"January 01, 2019".

How can a table be sorted by date, if it is using this human readable format?

```
+------------+---------------+------------------+
| Name       | Description   | Date             |
+------------+---------------+------------------+
| Column 1   | Description 1 | January 01, 2005 |
| Column 2   | Description 2 | April 03, 2055   |
| Column 3   | Description 3 | October 31, 1920 |
+------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have access to ISO format or timestamp also in your data source?

Comment: Yes, I can have a hidden column that is an integer in the form of 'yyyymmdd'. Is that ISO format?

Comment: Not quite iso but should be a simple numeric sort. The docs show how to use a hidden column for sorting ( goes in column definitions)

Comment: How can I associate that when clicking the date column? It is sorted by Name by default.

Comment: In the column definitions you tell it to use the hidden column for sorting Date. I haven't looked for a long time but I know it is documented and might even be examples(s)